# How can i set MySQL mode to 'ANSI' from an SSIS package

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that transfers data from MSSQL server 2008 R2 table to MySQL 5.6.

```
    Set sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ANSI_QUOTES'
```

In the package, prior to executing the Data Flow Task that does the transfer, i'm first executing the command above but when the real data transfer step is reached i'm getting error similar to below

> An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"myColumn1", "myColumn1") VALUES (?, ?)'

As i investigated this, it appeared as though the error can be resolved by setting the MySQL mode to 'ANSI' but since i'm new to MySQL, i was thinking the above command was already setting the Mode to 'ANSI', is this true?

If this isn't true, how can i set the MySQL Mode to 'ANSI' from an SSIS package?

Also what privileges would i need on the MySQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the trick is to get SSIS to run this `SET SESSION sql_mode= 'ansi';` command before inserting the data without messing with the package itself?

The easiest way is to have the ODBC driver send the command at the point SSIS opens the connection, this can be configured in the settings of the ODBC source

REF: http://www.ash.burton.fm/blogs/2011/03/pgsql_ssis_mysql and indeed this resolved the error i have facing.